# How to use multiple firebase apps in python?

Tags: python, firebase, flask, google-cloud-firestore

I'm wondering, how exactly would I initialize multiple firebase projects in one python file.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I did this:

```
default_app2 = initialize_app(cred2, name='todo-app')
db2 = firestore.client(default_app2)
```

all I needed to do was add the 'name' filter in the initialize_app() and the variable name in firestore.client()

Answer (score 0):

If you are initializing multiple apps and accessing their respective firestore, you should specify the app (E.g `default-app2` ) while creating the client. Otherwise firebase might create client for any of the many apps you must have initialized

Edit: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_multiple_apps